# Hibernate: Single @Id not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I got the following Java Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="years")
public class Year implements Serializable {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "year", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 4)
 private int year;
 @Id
 @Column(name = "ayear", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 4)
 private int ayear = 0;

 @Column(name="sum_carbs", nullable=false)
 private double sum_carbs = 0;
 ...
}
```

When I remove the 'ayear' Property from the class and the Database, hibernate is throwing

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class database.databaseObjects.Year. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class database.databaseObjects.Year

But with both @Id's and the representing field in the database, everithing works as expected, except I have an annoying useless DB field.

SQL Code of the Years Table

```
CREATE TABLE `years` (
`year` int(4) NOT NULL,
`sum_carbs` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`avg_carbs` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`min_carbs` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999999999',
`max_carbs` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`count_carbs` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `years` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`year`);
```

Comment: Please check if your ID column name in the database is incorrect. My guess is your column name is not 'year'.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but checked that multiple times, but I added the SQL for the table

Comment: Is it because your CREATE statement is missing a PRIMARY KEY constraint..?

Comment: @SarathChandra sry I forgot to add the primary command to my post, but I used it in my Application. But good hint.

Comment: It looks like Hibernate is confusing between the column name and class name. When seeing the column name as `year`, it is treating it as the class. Can you try renaming the column to `year_id` and see if that helps ?

Comment: Tried that but only in a dirty way, maybe I forgot something. I will redo it later and test it again. But after my short test it doesn't seem to work. year = (Year_class)dbm.get(Year_class.class,new Integer(2016)); when I use that java I get an Integer which I cannot Cast to Year, when I use year = (Year_class)dbm.get(Year_class.class,year); Java throws the error mentioned in my first post

Comment: Tested again, but seems not to work.

Comment: When I use Hibernates Session.byId it works, but I thinks its strange that I cannot use the other method. It makes my application unnessasary complex in that case, cause I have to check if I want to retrieve Year or Day (another db object) or so on and get the first by id and the other by Object.